# Stub or mock fake req, res and go through stubbed function

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

My task is to create account in database through API. I want to unit test working of this API but I don't want to hit real database and create an account.

I want to go through this function and fake the request and response. Currently I am able to fake request and response but not go through the function.

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const Acreation = require('../accountsCreation');
var sinon =require('sinon');

describe('account creation Route', function() {
    let req;
    let res;
    beforeEach(function()
    {
        req = {
            body: {
               "accountid":"xyz",
               "accountname":"newAccount"

            }
        };

        res = {
            json:sinon.spy()
        }
    });
    afterEach(function()
    {
        console.log("done test");
    });

    it('should return success on sucessful account creation',function(done){
      var createAccountStub=sinon.stub(Acreation,'accountsCreation').returns("Success");
      Acreation.accountsCreation(req,res);
      expect(createAccountStub.called).to.be.true;
      expect(createAccountStub.returnValues[0]).to.deep.equal("Success");

      done();
    })
})
```

Comment: Any error response you got? Can you share the source file as well?

Comment: Is there any error?